# What translates compiler and interpreter code?

Tags: compilation, interpreter, translate

All programming languages are translated to machine code which is then executed by the hardware interpreter. However what translates the code of translators such as compiler code and interpreter code? A compiler translates source code but compiler also written in some language so what translates the compiler code/interpeter code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> All programming languages are translated to machine code which is then executed by the hardware interpreter.

That's not necessarily true. Barring JIT compilation, interpreters usually don't translate the given language to machine code.

> However what translates the code of translators such as compiler code and interpreter code?

If you write your interpreter or compiler in C (for example), it will be translated to machine code by a C compiler - just like any other C program would. Compilers and interpreters aren't special in that regard.

Comment: Thanks @sepp2k but how can a computer execute source code without knowing its specific machine language implementation? Also if everything has a compiler/interpreter then does not it continue to ad fininitum?

Comment: @MohammadRahman "how can a computer execute source code without knowing its specific machine language implementation?" In case of a normal (i.e. non-JIT compiling) interpreter, the source code is executed by the interpreter, not by the CPU. And then of course the interpreter itself is executed by the CPU.

Comment: @MohammadRahman "Also if everything has a compiler/interpreter then does not it continue to ad fininitum?" Machine code doesn't need a compiler or interpreter. So that's where the loop breaks: The first compiler was written in machine code and thus didn't need any prior compiler to exist. Or more accurately: the first compiler was written in an assembly language (i.e. a text based version of machine code) and the first assembler was written in machine code.